# Insert number into ordered arrayList

Tags: java

I have an interesting problem on how to insert any number into an ordered ArrayList. Lets say the user enters `[12,34,37,60,89]`; the method `addListElement()` should traverse the array to find the index where the new element will go.

The user enters the number 50, the new array should be `[12,34,37,50,60,89]`. I used a for loop to traverse the ArrayList, but I'm not sure about my if() statement.

```
public void addListElement() {
    System.out.println("Add number to arrayList");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();

    int loc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aryList.size(); i++) {
        if (number > 0 && i < loc) {
            loc++;
        }
    }

    aryList.add(loc, number);
    System.out.println(aryList.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please look over your code sample again. It looks like you missed some curly brackets here and there...

Comment: @RichardPena The code sample is fine. No necessary brackets are missing.

Comment: @Vulcan You're right, but it's not exactly a good idea to skip them, it just hurts readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work too. Since the list is already in ascending order, when ever you find the number in list bigger than the current one, insert the new number one index before this number in arrayList..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < aryList.size(); i++) {
    if (aryList.get(i)>number) {
       break;
    }
  loc++;
}
```

Comment: basically you are searching... then why not use a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: I totally agree with you that better algorithm can be used. however, OP was just not sure about his conditional statement. I just modified the condition to fill his needs.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
int position = Collections.binarySearch(aryList, number);
aryList.add(position < 0 ? -position - 1 : position, number);
```

*Edit* thanks for pointing out the old code crashes if the number is already present

Comment: Interesting. But will throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the `List` already contains the element to insert.

Comment: I probably have to use try/catch block and put the condition for out of bounds exception.

Comment: I wouldn't to that Nic. This code is close enough to a real solution. 
maybe `int index = Collections.binarySearch(aryList, number);` `aryList.add(index < 0 ? -index - 1 : index, number);`

Comment: Does the same code also works when you try to delete number from array, and also delete number that does not exist?

Comment: it would be a bit different for remove ... `int pos = Collections.binarySearch(list, thingToRemove);
if (pos >= 0) list.remove(pos);`

Answer (score 2):

You would want to make use of the [`List<E>.add(int idx, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method.  The idea behind inserting the element in order is that, for some array *a*, element *a<sub>i</sub>*, and for some integer *n*:

a<sub>i</sub> <= n <= a<sub>i+1</sub> , 0 < i < len(a)-1.

```
// edge case:  Size one list, number coming in is smaller.
if(aryList.size() == 1 && aryList.get(0) >= number) {
    aryList.add(0, number);
} else {
    for(int i = 0; i < aryList.size()-1; i++) {
        if(number >= aryList.get(i) && number <= aryList.get(i+1)) {
            aryList.add(i, number);
        }
    }
    // number is the largest seen; add it to the end.
    aryList.add(number);
}
```

Comment: No.  Since I'm not iterating all the way to the end of the list, even if I'm at the last iterable element, I still won't step off of the list.

Comment: It would get tacked on at the end.  I didn't cover that, good catch @Geobits.

Comment: thats the reason there was no exception. Was wondering about that. and you also have one missing parethesis at the end of the condition. ie need one ')' after aryList.get(i+1)

Comment: The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int

Comment: This means your ArrayList doesn't have a type associated with it.  You can either cast each call to get() as Integer, or instantiate your ArrayList with `List<Integer> aryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.  The latter is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
int loc = 0;
int prevNumber = aryList.get(0);
for(int i = 1; i<aryList.size(); i++){
            if(number > prevNumber && number <= aryList.get(i)){ 
               return i;
            }
    prevNumber = aryList.get(i);
  }
```

Comment: get the number at ith location. (however he has implemented that code)

Comment: The object being used at that instance is an ArrayList.  [ArrayList doesn't have that method listed in the API.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  So I'm still confused as to where it came from (maybe you meant get(i)?).

Comment: oh yes, edit it if you want :) that's right, get(i) is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the index as long as there are more elements and the number is less than the current element. You will also have to check that i != list.size() when finished for cases when the user gives a number that is larger than any number currently in the list.

```
while (number >= 0 && number <= list.get(i) && i < list.size()) {
    i++;
}

list.add(i, number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your Elements are ordered by an ascendant order

```
 public void insert(int x){
        // loop through all elements
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            // if the element you are looking at is smaller than x, 
            // go to the next element
            if (arrayList.get(i) < x) continue;
            // if the element equals x, return, because we don't add duplicates
            if (arrayList.get(i) == x) return;
            // otherwise, we have found the location to add x
            arrayList.add(i, x);
            return;
        }
        // we looked through all of the elements, and they were all
        // smaller than x, so we add x to the end of the list
        arrayList.add(x);
    }
```

If you want to insert duplicates in your ArrayList just remove the line of code

```
if (arrayList.get(i) == x) return;
```